# pip install dynamic-dynamodb InsecurePlatformWarning

Tags: python, django, git, python-2.7

`I am running AWS EC2
OS:ubuntu 14.04

python --version
Python 2.6.9

pip --version
pip 7.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages (python 2.6)`

`$>pip install dynamic-dynamodb`

```
`Collecting dynamic-dynamodb
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/sitepackages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLCoenter code herentext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Using cached dynamic-dynamodb-2.0.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-QLQE6u/dynamic-dynamodb/setup.py", line 36, in <module>
        install_requires=return_requires(),
      File "/tmp/pip-build-QLQE6u/dynamic-dynamodb/setup.py", line 19, in return_requires
        install_requires.append('ordereddict >= 1.1')
    AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'


Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-QLQE6u/dynamic-dynamodb`
```

--------------------- OR ------------------

I pull it from git

```
$>git pull https://github.com/sebdah/dynamic-dynamodb.git

$> cd dynamic-dynamodb

$>make install

python setup.py build
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 36, in <module>
    install_requires=return_requires(),
  File "setup.py", line 19, in return_requires
    install_requires.append('ordereddict >= 1.1')
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

Any advice what do i miss ?!

Comment: There seems to be an extra comma in their `setup.py` after ] on line 17, making the `install_requires` a tuple with a list inside rather than just a list. This only happens on Python < 2.7, as the append isn't executed otherwise. You could try removing the comma manually in the git repository to see if it has any effect.

Comment: Thanks very much. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Juuso Meriläinen.
Looks like [this](https://github.com/sebdah/dynamic-dynamodb/blob/master/setup.py#L17) comma breaks everything:

```
def return_requires():
    install_requires = [
        'boto >= 2.29.1',
        'requests >= 0.14.1',
        'logutils >= 0.3.3',
        'retrying >= 1.3.3'
    ], # <---- it breaks the code
    if sys.version_info < (2, 7):
        install_requires.append('ordereddict >= 1.1')
    return install_requires
```

You can try to remove it manually in your local code. Also it would be nice to send pull request the dynamic-dynamodb repo.